# Storing restaurant categories in GeoDjango project

Tags: django, database-design, django-models

I am making a geo django backend for an iPhone app. The iphone app sends users current location to the backend, which returns nearby restaurants (something similar to Foursquare and Yelp.)

I am not entirely sure how to store the cuisine for the restaurants. I need an option where the user can  look up/select a specific cuisine for example only Chinese food. Should I create a seperate model for restaurant cuisine and have one to many relationship with the restaurants ? or should I use boolean value like this:

```
models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here is the code for my Model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gis_models
from django.contrib.gis import geos
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length = 12)
    cuisine = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    eatingOptions = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    location = gis_models.PointField(u'Latitude/Longitude', geography=True, blank=True, null=True)

    # Query Manager
    gis = gis_models.GeoManager()
    objects = models.Manager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only you and your requirements can answer that.

1. If you create a separate model and have a relationship it will be more flexible, you can have different cuisines without changing the model. Best option if your database will have multiple types of cuisine.
2. If you choose to use a BooleanField like *is_chinese* then it will work only for chinese cuisine. This is the best option if you only care for one type of cuisine.

Don't worry if you make a bad judgement when developing (at least on an early stage), [django has your back](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/).

Hope that helps.